# Access Samba (Linux) File Share w/o using "AllowInsecureGuestAuth" on Clients

Tags: windows, samba

I have to set a registry key on all Windows 10 clients since the Windows 10 1709 update, because MS disabled the guest account access by default [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1167289/issue-with-smb-cifs-on-openmediavault-3-0-59-with-windows-10-pc/1171066#1171066) [MS](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/error-the-account-is-not-authorized-to-login-from/ffa63cc0-92d0-4639-9e3f-4d50100c1841) [TechJourney](https://techjourney.net/cannot-connect-to-cifs-smb-samba-network-shares-shared-folders-in-windows-10/):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
"AllowInsecureGuestAuth"=dword:00000001
```

MS recommends:

> The recommended solution is to add an explicit account and password on your NAS device [...]

I have this set up. To access the shares on the samba server you have to type username and pw, but w/o setting the above registry key, the client PC cannot even list the available file shares on the samba server. What is wrong in my configuration?

```
[global]
workgroup = <censored>
server string = <censored>
interfaces = lo enp3s0 <censored>/25
bind interfaces only = yes
hosts allow = 127. <censored>

allow insecure wide links = yes

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 50
log level = 1

# Standalone Server Options 
security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam

map to guest = Bad User
guest account = nobody

smb encrypt = auto

# Browser Control Options 
local master = yes
os level = 255
preferred master = yes
domain master = yes

# Name Resolution 
wins support = yes

# Share Definitions 
[home]
comment = <censored>
path = /home
public = no
browseable = yes
writable = yes
create mode = 0660
directory mode = 0770
veto files = /lost+found/pub/user/backupbot/

[public]
comment = <censored>
path = /home/pub/
public = no
browseable = yes
writable = yes
create mode = 0660
directory mode = 2770
veto files = /TempDrive/Papierkorb/
inherit permissions = Yes

# allow access from public to media/extra/Software 
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
map to guest = Never
```

---

The problem was

```
map to guest = Bad User
```

[samba.org](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#MAPTOGUEST) says

> Note that this parameter is needed to set up "Guest" share services. This is because in these modes the name of the resource being requested is not sent to the server until after the server has successfully authenticated the client so the server cannot make authentication decisions at the correct time (connection to the share) for "Guest" shares.

After disabling map to guest (which means the default "map to guest = Never" is used) Windows 10 (1709+) client machines can connect, also I do not completely understand why. Please comment if you can explain this.

Comment: You just saved my day. This issue also applies to https://github.com/namjaejeon/ksmbd ksmbd.mountd under DD-WRT and possibly others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not help me. I found a working one in a [comment of another site](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-cannot-access-samba-share-as-guest/):

```
**ADD THESE LINES**
[global]
client min protocol = SMB3
client max protocol = SMB3
restrict anonymous = 2

**REMOVE ANY**
map to guest
guest ok
```

This seems to raise the security bar for Windows10 clients and forces to to the right connection. This should also work for Windows8 client since they also support [SMB3](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#SERVERMAXPROTOCOL).